# Variadic templates передача и возврат по ссылке

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename... Args>
void foo(Args&... args)
{
    size_t param_count = sizeof...(args);

    std::string sarray[] = { (args)... };  // <= Copy-array

    sarray[0] = "Goodbye";
}

int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "Hello";
    std::string str2 = "World";

    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << str2 << std::endl;

    foo(str1, str2);

    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << str2 << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Возможно ли при передаче пака параметров принять его по ссылке и что-то изменить в одном из параметров?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Навскидку придумалось - сработать через указатели:

```
template<typename... Args>
void foo(Args&... args)
{
    constexpr size_t param_count = sizeof...(args);
    string* sarray[param_count] = { &args... };  // <= Copy-array
    *(sarray[0]) = "Goodbye";
}
```

Comment: а  вообще легально преобразование пака к массиву? `std::string sarray[] = { (args)... };`

Comment: @goldstar_labs Гм. Я скорее практик. Со стратегическими вопросами - это к сове из анекдота... VC++ берет, GCC (https://ideone.com/GR0Fwe) берет. Явных ошибок не вижу. Копаться в стандарте, чтоб найти несоответствие какой-то букве, которая все равно нигде не реализована, откровенно говоря, не хочется... Разве что - очевидно, что это писано конкретно для `string`ов.

Comment: Я вас понял) спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 4):

Альтернативный вариант: воспользоваться `std::tie`:

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Args>
void foo(Args & ... args)
{
    auto items{::std::tie(args...)}; // кортеж ссылок
    ::std::get<0>(items).assign("Goodbye"); // проверка индекса во время компиляции
}
```

Для простого случая, когда все аргументы имеют одинаковый тип, можно написать нешаблонную функцию воспользовавшись `std::initializer_list`:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

void foo(::std::initializer_list<::std::reference_wrapper<::std::string>> args)
{
    auto p_args{args.begin()};
    p_args[0].get() = "Goodbye";
}

int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "Hello";
    std::string str2 = "World";

    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << str2 << std::endl;

    foo({str1, str2});

    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << str2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, такой вариант даже лучше, но в данном конкретном случае неприменим

Comment: @goldstar_labs Почему не применим?

Comment: Там внутри цикл, а std::get<N> - это время компиляции, я глянул как сделать std::get времени выполнения и там не так просто.

Comment: @goldstar_labs Так а обычный цикл по аргументам вообще сделать не получится, у них же может быть разный тип (и в массив их засунуть, как того советуют в соседнем ответе, тоже не получится). А если вы передаете в фунцию де-факто массив из элементов одного типа, то наверное стоит использовать `std::initializer_list`

Comment: Вы абсолютли правы, но в реальном кейсе всё чуть сложнее, функция - вариадик, но передаются туда только стд::строки, зачем и отчего так - это отдельный вопросю

Comment: @goldstar_labs Добавил вариант для такого случая.